# Possible Drupal 7 alternatives for the Gallery Assist module?

Tags: gallery, drupal

The [Gallery Assist](https://www.drupal.org/project/gallery_assist) module provides an easy way to create image galleries in a Drupal site. However this module is not available (yet) for Drupal  version 7 (only for version 6).

So since Drupal 6 is no longer supported either, I wonder what the recommended modules are that do support Drupal 7, and which might provide a possible alternative for [Gallery Assist](https://www.drupal.org/project/gallery_assist).

Here are some of the features about the [Gallery Assist](https://www.drupal.org/project/gallery_assist) module, which I would like to also be able to use in Drupal 7:

- Integration with [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views).
- Multi-language support.
- Configurable display options for the galleries.

Comment: What features do you need? Please append the explanation as if Gallery Assist had never existed. Then ask us to reopen, cheers! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Talking Drupal #083](http://www.talkingdrupal.com/083) is a great podcast about creating a Gallery, and includes a lot of recommended modules for it. Just to mention a few of them (mentioned on the linked page):

- [Gallery formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/galleryformatter)

  > ... provides a CCK formatter for image fields, which will turn any image field into a jQuery Gallery.
- [Views Slideshow](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow)

  > ... can be used to create a slideshow of any content (not just images) that can appear in a View. Powered by jQuery, it is heavily customizable: you may choose slideshow settings for each View you create.
- [Flexslider](https://www.drupal.org/project/flexslider)

  > ... integrates the [Flex Slider library](https://www.drupal.org/project/galleryformatter) with Drupal and several contributed modules which allows you to build responsive, resizable slideshows. Meaning the slideshows automatically adapt to the size of the browser window or device.
- [Node Gallery](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_gallery)

  > ... allows you to create multimedia galleries where both the galleries and the gallery items are nodes (as opposed to gallery items being file fields, like [Media Gallery](https://www.drupal.org/project/flexslider)).

Comment: One answer per software recommendation, with a screenshot and cost info, would be better.